# Associating npm package with local typescript definitions file

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I am using an npm package (say foo) and during development I would like to associate this package with a local (committed along with project files) typescript definitions file. I explicitly do not intend to publish the definitions file as an npm package because as of now it is incomplete and covers only the parts of the library I actually use.

So far I have tried the following:

Adding the following to tsconfig.json

```
"typeRoots": [
  "./node_modules/@types",
  "./src/types"
],
```

And added definition file in `./src/types/foo/index.d.ts`. However neither VSCode nor the typescript webpack-loader are able to associate imports from 'foo' with the exports in the definition file.

What is the right approach for handling this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's pretty much what I did [here](https://github.com/D10221/dns-js-dts)

created "my Type" for an existing lib 
following the instructions from [@types](https://github.com/types/guidelines)
and publish it to "my" Github.
instead of publishing to @types

finally

```
npm i git+https://github.com/my/repo.git
```

it's going to end up in node_modules/@types/chosen-name
exactly where tsc expect it to be

I didn't try but I don't see a reason why it shouldn't work from other sources

```
npm i ../myrepo
```

Comment: because of package.json ... "name": "@types/whatever"

Comment: Yeah, realized that shortly after posting my comment. This works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a reference to the type definition in "files" section of tsconfig.json fixes the issue:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": { ... },
    "files" : ["./src/types/foo.d.ts"]
}
```

This [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41324004/476712) proposed by Dan works too, but requires more work - if one intends to publish the definitions eventually that is the ideal approach.